# Upload Json file items to sitecore Media Library using Sitecore Item Web API

Tags: json, sitecore, asp.net-web-api

I would like to extract the items from Json file from my local to media library of the Sitecore Content using sitecore item Web API. Does anyone have excamples to access WebApi and upload to the media library items?
thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post may help you. It has a helper to upload files to Sitecore`s Media Library:

http://www.sitecoreinsight.com/how-create-media-items-using-sitecore-item-web-api/

To create regular items (not in the media library) I suggest you to use this tool:

http://sitecorecreative.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/sitecore-web-api-client-library/

Comment: Thanks RobertoBr, I am using the first one and getting 404 not found error when I post, my sitecore site is running. the url in post I am passing is http://localsite/-/item/v1/?name=example&sc_itemid={4C1272F4-0B29-4FD2-A0AA-E81460E705E0}&sc_database=master&payload=content

Comment: Are you passing only the domain or the entire query when you instantiate the helper class? Should be like in the sample: Sitecore.Insight.MediaPost(@"h t t p://localsite/", @"sitecore\admin", "b");

Comment: thanks Robert, I was not configuring the webItemAPI.config I thought in sitecore 7.2 it's already done. SO, configured that one and it's working fine. But the deleted items from Web API still show in tree, but Web API call cannot find that one. could you please also suggest on that one?

Comment: Never saw that happening. Are you sure the item still there, are you looking in the same db ?

Comment: That's correct Robert, although I was using same database for web and master in connection string, it was taking a while to synch. Then I tried to use ../path/Item?sc_database=master in get, it returns " ...database is denied. Only members of the Sitecore Client Users role can switch databases.." I am using "sitecore\admin and  b for credentials.